# How to include custom classes in GWT

Tags: maven, gwt

I am trying to include my own package in a GWT bundle. If I try to use the Java class from my own custom package/class in GWT application I am getting the error *"No source code is available for the type. Did you forget to inherit a required module"* while building with maven.

I tried the solutions below to resolve the above mentioned problem:

1. I inherited the custom package in `gwt.xml`
2. I included the custom package in `pom.xml` of GWT application for maven
3. Installed the jar in repository

But i'm still getting the above mentioned error.

**Note: I am not getting this error in eclipse only during command line maven build.**

How can I include my own package in a GWT bundle using maven?

**wmc.gwt.xml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='wmc'>

  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>


  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->
  <inherits name="com.smartgwtpro.SmartGwtProNoTheme" />
  <inherits name="com.smartgwtpro.tools.Tools" />

  <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoTheme"/>    
  <inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.enterprise.Enterprise"/>
  <inherits name="com.smartclient.theme.enterprise.EnterpriseResources"/>

  <inherits name='com.extjs.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
  <inherits name='com.googlecode.gchart.GChart'/>
  <inherits name='pl.balon.gwt.diagrams.Diagrams'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization'/>
  <inherits name='com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.gwt-dnd'/>

   <!-- inherit the customized package for accessing the method of that bundle -->
  <inherits name='com.bf.service.management'/>

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='com.isoft.web.viaductWebConsole.client.MonitorConsole'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='wmc/client'/>
  <source path='wmc'/>
  <source path='web'/>
```

The above mentioned is the gwt.xml , where you'll find `<inherits name='com.bf.service.management'/>` - this is my customized package which I need to use in the GWT application but when I try to build the GWT code I am getting the **"Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1 : compile  on project wmc: GWT Module com.bf.service.management not found in project sources or resources"**

Comment: are you creating two different maven project or maintaining in a single package

Comment: Hi mohammed i am just maintaining a single package and building that package through maven. For reference i have updated the main question section with the gwt.xml file .

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with your custom package?

Comment: No what i am feeling is the method of my custom package is not recognized by the GWT complier . Even i have used this custom package method in some other package that time its working fine . Only problem occurs if i use that in GWT application

Comment: Maybe you're using some features of Java that GWT can't compile? Check the JRE whitelist: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html (sorry I can't be of more help)

Answer (score 1):

For me this only ever happens if:

1. You haven't put the correct `inherits` statement in my `project.gwt.xml` file.
2. The `inherits` statements are in the wrong order. Try putting it higher up the list.

As long as you have the correct `inherits` statements and the right dependencies in your `pom.xml` it should work. Try playing around a little.

Comment: Hi , I have inherited the customized package what i am trying to use in GWT application ingwt.xml file and also added the dependency in pom.xml . For your reference i have added the gwt.xml file in the main question section

Comment: Try putting `<inherits name='com.bf.service.management'/>` just under the `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>` line? Changing the order usually works for me.

Comment: ok i will try that . And one more question how to print the message in gwt classes/package is System.out.println is supported in GWT application?

Comment: I even tried in re-ordering the the inherit tag under the com.google.gwt.user.User but it showing the same error that the com.bf.service.management is not found in gwt

Comment: Yes, `System.out` will work fine, but in the longer term you should thinkg about using `gwt-log`.